# Vue iteracion de datos

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

estoy iterando unos datos con una propiedad computada en un v-for
uso axios para obtener datosde una api externa veran el codigo

```
                      <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>casa</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <<tr v-for="values in juegosYlogros " :key="values.id">
                                <td>{{values.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{values.ganajuegoCasa}}</td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**en el js**

```
 computed:{
        juegosYlogros: function () {
            var me = this
            let juegosYlogros = this.games.map(p =>{
                axios.get('https://api.betsapi.com/v1/bet365/start_sp?token='+ this.apikey + '&FI='+ p.id)
                    .then(response =>{
                        var respuesta = response.data.results

                        p.ganajuegoCasa = respuesta.find((el) => { return el.FI === p.id}).main.sp.full_time_result[0].odds
                        console.log(p.ganajuegoCasa)
                    });
                return p
            })
                return juegosYlogros
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ProximosJuegos(sport_id, token, day, page, league_id) {
            var me = this;
            axios.get('https://api.b365api.com/v1/bet365/upcoming?sport_id=' + sport_id + '&token=' + token + '&day=' + day + '&page=' + page)
                .then(response => {
                    me.games = response.data.results;


                })
        },
```

veran con el metodo obtego todos los juegos 
y con la propiedad computada hago un bucle para obtener los logros por cada uno de los juegos obtenidos
y en genera esta bien[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver si cumple el requisito pero cuando va al v-for parece que no espera a que se complete la peticion ajax y no muestra el logro en la tabla
parece que itera los datos en el v-for antes de realizar toda la accion de la propieda computada

Comment: No es lo que esta pasando. Si completa la peticion. El problema es que la propiedad computada no se ejecuta, porque tu objeto "no cambio". Vos pensas que cambio, pero como bien esta explicado en el manual de VUE, cuando un objeto (en este caso tu array) cambia un valor, no ocurre la reactividad, porque las propiedades del objeto no son reactivas. Mira aca: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: y como hago amigo

Comment: Ahi te pongo una respuesta. Pero en el manual esta la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Las propiedades de un objeto no son reactivas, y esta explicado en el manual de vue [aca](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats).

Para que tu array sea reactiva, asigna lo nuevo que recibis usando un objet.Assign

```
Object.assign(tuobjeto, elnuevoobjeto)
```

Asi, que en el regreso de tu axios, deberias hacer algo asi:

```
Object.assign(me.games,response.data.results);
```

Y de esta forma, el objeto reaccionara y se ejecutara tu v-for.